# Install conda forge - Error in uninstalling- conda-4.5.4-py36-Access Denied

Tags: python-3.x, conda, matplotlib-basemap, access-denied

I'm trying to install matplotlib Basemap. After doing some research I found that Basemap has a conflict with python 3.x. This however can be resolved by typing the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

in the anaconda cmd prompt

everything was working well until I received the following error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

Anyone else had this issue and how can I resolve it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue is by running as root/admin when running the anaconda prompt command.

This worked. Just search for anaconda prompt and instead of clicking, right click then choose the option 'run as administrator'

It worked!!
Thank you